# Можно ли запретить смену ориентации при просмотре мобильного сайта?

Tags: html, javascript, css

Можно ли запретить смену ориентации при просмотре мобильного сайта?
Оставив только портретную.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[можно](http://www.sitepoint.com/introducing-screen-orientation-api/)

Comment: @woland, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Было бы здорово если бы вы добавили ваше экспертное мнение к ссылке.